# field labels not getting refreshed when i switch between the languages by choosing the language radio button

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Hi Iam pretty new to stackoverflow and extjs4.1 too.Our application works in the below way.
There is manageNrc.js, which has entry in index.html ,on load of  which(managenrc.js) it creates the components managenrcgrid .js(EXt gridpanel) and managenrcform.js(Ext form panel).So far so good.But when the user toggles the radio button right on the top of the page.application takes  him to the login page.This time it is expected to reload the components and show all fieldlabels of the components in the french language user selected. I implemented localisation with two arrays in a json file nrclabels.json.

```
var nrcLABELS = {
    "EN": {
        "user_id": "User ID"
    }
    "FR": {
        "user_id": "ID utilisateur"
    }
}
```

The radio button gives the value selected like EN or FR so that the appropriate keys/values from json are picked and shown for fieldlabels.but its not happening so.

Comment: I did notice that when I was formatting your question you are missing a comma between both objects in the nrcLABELS object.

Comment: Thanks Reimius..Infact,when i kept a console.log to check if the right key /values are picked up ...yes right key/values are picked up.The piece of code was some sort of pseudo code which may not be syntactically correct.....I see some posts suggesting items in initcomponent but i didnt get the gist of it :(